# How can I get proper linting for SCSS files using SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext2, sass

I'm constantly having to disable linting when working with SCSS files in Sublime Text 2.

Anyone know of a way to get proper linting for SCSS files in ST2?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there is [no sass linter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/200) available, so until there is, it is not possible.  However, that thread shows you how to disable linting for scss files with SublimeLinter.

Comment: [Scss linter](https://github.com/causes/scss-lint), but not integrated into sublime, yet.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, there is no linter available for SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently found this add on for sublime linter to add SCSS syntax

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-scss-lint

Comment: I found that, too. But I'm having a hard time getting it working. Were you successful? I have a question about it over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140947/sublimelinter-scss-lint-not-linting