# SublimeLinter SCSS-Lint Not Linting?

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

With SublimeLiner debug set to on, I see this in the console that makes it appear the linter is loaded:

```
SublimeLinter: scss activated: /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3/bin/scss-lint
```

scss-lint is in fact in that directory.

But I see this when a .scss file is edited:

```
SublimeLinter: scss: _layout.scss ['/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3/bin/scss-lint'] 
SublimeLinter: scss output:
/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'scss-lint' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3/bin/scss-lint:22:in `<main>'
```

No syntax errors are highlighted.

Does that provide any clues?

Comment: I think your path is set incorrectly because you're seeing `ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3` in the last line of the trace, then `ruby-2.0.0-p247` above it. Try the setting suggested here:
http://blog.jameschevalier.us/how-to-make-sublimelinter-work-with-ruby-rvm/

and if that doesn't help, start troubleshooting from: 
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#troubleshooting-build-systems

Answer (score 2):

Current version of Scss-Lint doesn't support RVM,
You can get more information at https://github.com/attenzione/SublimeLinter-scss-lint/issues/5

There are several workarounds

- Start Sublime Text 3 from the Terminal with subl (This actually works for me).
- Install the scss-lint gem into the @global gemset with `rvm @global do gem install scss-lint` and start Sublime Text 3 normally. Bear in mind this kinda misses the the whole RVM point (Didn't verify it myself).